# arc land fails with EXCEPTION: Command failed with error #1! COMMAND git commit -F /private/var/folders/

Tags: reactjs, typescript, git, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to land a local branch with the remote origin branch via Phabricator, but I get the following error:

```
Exception 
Command failed with error #1!
COMMAND
git commit -F /private/var/folders/xy/jmw3nv_s4rn0ywp858_4g78w0000gp/T/493vbjhee2g44cso/72559-4re42h

STDOUT
(empty)

STDERR
yarn run v1.22.19
warning ../../../package.json: No license field
$ /Users/tz/Desktop/feature-ul-post-detection1010/tezign-intelligence-frontend-dam/node_modules/.bin/lerna run --concurrency 1 --stream precommit --since HEAD --exclude-dependents
lerna notice cli v4.0.0
lerna info versioning independent
lerna notice filter changed since "HEAD"
lerna notice filter excluding dependents
lerna info Looking for changed packages since HEAD
lerna info Executing command in 1 package: "yarn run precommit"
dam: warning ../../../../../package.json: No license field
dam: $ yarn lint-staged
dam: warning ../../../../../package.json: No license field
dam: $ /Users/tz/Desktop/feature-ul-post-detection1010/tezign-intelligence-frontend-dam/packages/dam-app/node_modules/.bin/lint-staged
dam: [STARTED] Preparing...
dam: [SUCCESS] Preparing...
dam: [STARTED] Running tasks...
dam: [STARTED] Running tasks for src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}
dam: [STARTED] Running tasks for src/**/*.{css,less,sass,scss}
dam: [STARTED... (1,427 more byte(s)) ...
(Run with `--trace` for a full exception trace.)
```

How can I solve this problem？

Comment: Please elaborate on what exactly are you doing to reproduce the error? What is Phabricator?

Comment: I switched your [tag:git] tag to [tag:dam] as Git isn't involved here other than running a Git hook (you seem to have this hook run yarn and dam), and [tag:automatic-reference-counting] was clearly wrong; I switched that for [tag:phabricator]. But whatever it is that says to run with `--trace` is probably right: I doubt anyone will be able to help without the trace output.